# firefox addons and their silly news tabs

Tags: firefox-extensions

Something like 30% of the addons I have in firefox update every other week and feel the need to pop open a tab about how awesome they are and all the cool things they changed.  I just don't care at all and I'm very annoyed by these news tabs.  When firefox opens, I want to see my home page. I've been looking for an addon to disable or kill them before I even have to look at them.  Rather like addblock-for-addons.

Short of finding a plugin that disables them, I'm seeking information about common interfaces so I can try to figure it out on my own.  I'm wondering if I could do it in greasemonkey somehow.  For example, is there something common about the url for the tabs?

Comment: If you never use the "save current session" feature, you might have some luck in running a script that somehow makes sure that, at startup, you end up having a single tab set to your homepage. Other than that, I'm afraid these plugins are just using standard features to display new pages, so I can't see how you could prevent them from doing it. Contacting each developer and telling them to offer an option to avoid that might be worth the trouble... given that they update so often ;)

Comment: I use Tab Mix Plus to control whether a new tab gets focus or not. This can be used as a workaround to see your homepage even when some tabs *pop up*. AFAIK it won't let you filter addon based tabs, but it may be configurable enough to keep all important tab behaviour and disable some unneeded Tab Mix Plus features.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to globally disable automatic updates of add-ons. This means that you can manually update add-ons - and deal with update news - at your leisure.

Clearly this has the disadvantage that your add-ons are not automatically updated. But Firefox (at least in version 4 beta 11) can be configured to automatically *check* for updates to add-ons (in `Options` > `Advanced` > `Update`), but without *installing* them (by deselecting `Update Add-ons Automatically` in the settings in `Add-ons Manager`).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no universal setting but individual addons may let you disable in their options. EG Noscript: Notifications > Display release notes on updates.